# Java 6: Creating locale with custom timezone

Tags: locale, java-6

I´m working with java 1.6_29 and I need to define several locales with different DateTimeElements ( for example First Day of week...) for Calendar instances.

In Java 1.4 we used LocaleElements_xx_XX classes (xx for language and country) as subclasses from ListResourceBundle to define new local elements, but in 1.6 this doesn´t work anymore. Does anyone has an idea how to do this in java 1.6? Thanks :)